# Why is my beam not propagating downstream from the mirror?

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{useNA=false}
\psset{pswarning}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](10,10)
\pnodes(1.5,7){A}
\pnodes(5,7){B}
\pnodes(8,7){C}
\pnodes(8,3){D}
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red!50!white, opacity=0.3, linestyle=none}
\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}
\psset{mirrorwidth=1.1}
\psset{loadbeampoints}
\psset{savebeampoints=true, loadbeampoints}

\begin{optexp}
\optsource[innerlabel, compname = start](A)(B){Beam}
\lens[compname=L1](A)(B){$L_1$}

%\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4, stopinside]{1-3}
\lens[compname=L2](B)(C){$L_2$}

\mirror[labelangle=-45, compname=M1](B)(C)(D){M}

\optbox[innerlabel, compname= D1](D)(D){Dump}
%\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.5](S){}(D)
%\addtopsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red!50!white, %opacity=0.3, linestyle=none}
%\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4, beaminsidelast](S){L1}{L2}

\end{optexp}
\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4, stopinside]{1-5}
%\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4,  beamdiv=-20]{2-3}
%\drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints]{M1}{D1}
%\drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints, beamdiv=-20, stopinside]{2-3}
%\drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints, stopinside]{3-5}
%\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.5]{4-5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I am unable to propagate the beam downstream.[image]

Answer (score 4):

The beam misses the `dump` optbox, because it is drawn in the wrong direction. You use the same node both as start and as end node, in which case the box is oriented horizontally, because we have no defined direction to which to align the box.

If you add a parameter `showifcnodes` to the optbox you'll see, where the optical interfaces are locate:

```
\optbox[innerlabel, compname= D1, showifcnodes](D)(D){Dump}
```

[image]

Use e.g. `C` as other reference point:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\psset{useNA=false, pswarning}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,2)(9,8)
\pnodes(1.5,7){A}
\pnodes(5,7){B}
\pnodes(8,7){C}
\pnodes(8,3){D}
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red!50!white, opacity=0.3, linestyle=none}
\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2, mirrorwidth=1.1}
\psset{savebeampoints, loadbeampoints}
\begin{optexp}
  \optsource[innerlabel, compname = start](A)(B){Beam}
  \lens[compname=L1](A)(B){$L_1$}
  \lens[compname=L2, n=1.33](B)(C){$L_2$}
  \mirror[labelangle=-45, compname=M1](B)(C)(D){M}
  \optbox[innerlabel, compname= D1, endbox](C)(D){Dump}
  \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4, stopinside]{1-5}
\end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, I also tweaked parameter `n` for `L2` a bit to get a reasonable beam diameter at `dump`.

[image]

Comment: Your answer definitely merited a positive vote.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Also, sorry if it is such a noob question, but honestly, it's, for me at least, a very hard package to learn since it's so verbose.

Comment: Don't worry :) It is indeed a quite complex package. I tried to insert a lot of examples, but it involves many concepts which aren't directly apparent.